# Python Tkinter - Put Vertical and Horizontal Scrollbar at the edge of the canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to put the horizontal and vertical scrollbars at the edge of the yellow canvas using Python tkinter, but whatever I do, it does not move and just stay inside the perimeter of the canvas. Why? Below is the image:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
 def render_gui(self):

    self.main_window = tk.Tk()
    self.main_window.geometry("1000x600")
    self.main_window.title("Damaged Text Document Virtual Restoration")
    self.main_window.resizable(True, True) 
    self.main_window.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.main_window.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.main_window.configure(highlightcolor="black")


    self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_window, bg = "yellow")
    self.main_canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.main_canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.main_canvas.yview)
    hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.main_canvas, orient="horizontal", command=self.main_canvas.xview)
    vsb.grid(row=1, column=50,columnspan = 20, sticky='ns')
    hsb.grid(row=20, column=1,rowspan = 20,sticky = 'wes')

    self.main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    self.main_window.mainloop()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has the canvas as the parent to the scrollbars.

Setting the scrollbars to have the same parent as the canvas, and changing a few placement things around, renders something workable:

```
import tkinter as tk

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.render_gui()

    def render_gui(self):
        self.main_window = tk.Tk()
        self.main_window.geometry("1000x600")
        self.main_window.title("Damaged Text Document Virtual Restoration")
        self.main_window.resizable(True, True) 
        self.main_window.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.main_window.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.main_window.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_window, bg = "yellow")
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.main_window, orient="vertical", command=self.main_canvas.yview)
        hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.main_window, orient="horizontal", command=self.main_canvas.xview)
        hsb.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "x")
        vsb.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.main_canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

        self.main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
        self.main_window.mainloop()

t = test()
```

[image]

Comment: 'pack' and 'grid' and 'place' can all be used in the same app at the same time. Its just a problem when you try to use them in the same container. It looks like to me the issue is what container the scroll bars are being added to is the problem.

Comment: If you would remove `It looks like pack and grid are being mixed, without reporting and error:` I will be glad to change my vote. That sentence implies that it should have thrown an error but didnt and that is not correct.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I think I've edited it to clarify what I meant by that statement, but in IDLE I did find it a little odd that I received no traceback error about mixing pack and grid, as I have in the past in similar situations. It may be due to how `Scrollbar`s are configured.

Comment: Your new statement is still incorrect. Pack is only being used in the root window and grid is being used inside of the Canvas. Those are 2 separate container and in that case it is perfectly acceptable to use pack and grid in this manor. Though personally I prefer to always use grid myself.

Comment: @Mike-SMT You're correct, I fixed the error without even noticing what it really was.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are putting the scrollbars inside the canvas, and you've put nothing else in the canvas.

When you use `grid` to put something inside another widget, rows and columns that are empty have a size of zero. Thus, even though you put the vertical scrollbar in column 50, columns 0 and 2-49 have a width of zero so column 50 appears on the left. (Column 1 is the width of the horizontal scrollbar.)

The same is true for the horizontal scrollbar - you're putting it in row 20, but rows 0 and 2-19 have a height of zero, so row 20 appears near the top.

Normally it's not a good idea to put scrollbars inside the canvas, since anything you draw on the canvas might be hidden or partially hidden by the scrollbars. If you want them to *appear* to be in the canvas, the simplest solution is to put both the canvas and the scrollbars inside a frame. You can then turn the border off on the canvas and turn the border on for the frame.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example():

 def render_gui(self):

    self.main_window = tk.Tk()
    self.main_window.geometry("1000x600")
    self.main_window.title("Damaged Text Document Virtual Restoration")
    self.main_window.resizable(True, True) 
    self.main_window.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.main_window.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.main_window.configure(highlightcolor="black")

    canvas_container = tk.Frame(self.main_window, bd=1, relief='sunken')
    canvas_container.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

    self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(canvas_container, bg = "yellow")
    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(canvas_container, orient="vertical", command=self.main_canvas.yview)
    hsb = tk.Scrollbar(canvas_container, orient="horizontal", command=self.main_canvas.xview)
    self.main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

    vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
    hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
    self.main_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    canvas_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    canvas_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.main_window.mainloop()

e = Example()
e.render_gui()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


janela = Tk()


scroll_x = Scrollbar(janela, orient="horizontal")
text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(janela, wrap=NONE)

text.config(xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)
scroll_x.configure(command=text.xview)

text.pack(fill=X)
scroll_x.pack(fill=X)

janela.mainloop()
```